# parallel computation fails

Tags: syntax, parallelization, list-manipulation

I have a code that evaluates matrix elements. It works correctly in sequential mode (one Kernel).
It involves a custom function `BariVi` which is declared earlier and `NonCommutativeMultiply`.
I tried to evaluate the matrix elements using `ParallelTable` after launching two Kernels.

```
LaunchKernels[2]
mat = ParallelTable[
BarVi[Distribute[x[i] ** tterm ** y[j]]], {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}]
```

The output is as if `BarVi` was not applied. I tried loading the two kernels from the beginning of the notebook. Same thing. What am I missing? With one Kernel everything is fine.

Comment: Please show a complete but minimal example that demonstrates the problem. See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

Comment: I believe, although not 100% sure, that you cannot parallelize a 2D array, i.e., it must be a 1D.  However you parallelize each row of the matrix:  ParallelTable[myArray[[i]],{i,1,n}] for a myarray[[i,j]] matrix with of course your function processing the entire row in one call.

Comment: `Distribute` does not parallelize. It seems that's the problem